# Is it okay to 'sandwich' rigid foam insulation between old and new sheet siding?

Tags: insulation, siding

I am putting new LP Smart Siding (4'x 8' and 3//8" thick) onto my house, which will overlay old T1-11 siding. I would like to put R-MAX 1/2" rigid foam insulation under the new siding.  Is this okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, that's fine. However, 1/2" is nowhere near enough insulation, and may actually create more problems than it solves, especially if you live in a cold area and your wall studs are deeper than 2x4. Thin foam like what you're proposing can cause wintertime condensation on the inside of whatever's right behind it. I would recommend *at least* a full inch, and more is better. Obviously this will complicate the trim around windows and doors, but you can easily install jamb extensions to handle that. 4 inches is not overkill, and if the depth is a problem, you could just remove the T1-11 siding first.

Another thing to mention: you have a perfect opportunity to add a radiant barrier, which will make a big difference if you live where it gets hot and sunny. Choose a foil-faced insulation board and face the foil outwards. Then fasten 1" thick vertical furring strips over the foam to create an air gap, and fasten your new siding to the furring strips. It will make a big difference.

Comment: We live in Oregon. There is currently R-11 fiberglass in the stud walls. We will use your suggestion and get the foil-faced insulation to go between the old and new sidings.

Comment: Here's the code for how much foam you need: http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/blogs/dept/musings/calculating-minimum-thickness-rigid-foam-sheathing

Comment: Short version: R-max is polyiso, which is R-5.5 per inch, so on the western side of the state (the marine climate), your half inch board idea is fine because code says you only need R-2.5. Anywhere else in the state, you'll need to upgrade to at least once inch to be safe and legal and get the required R-5. More is always better though.

Comment: Our basic question now is whether we can 'sandwich' the foam between the two types of siding without leaving any air gaps?

Comment: In general, yes, it's fine. However if you're going for the foil-faced radiant barrier approach, however, you need to leave at least half an inch of air space against the foil facer, preferably a full inch or more. Radiant barriers need to face open air or else they become literally useless. Using vertical furring strips like I've recommended will not only create this required air space, but they will also make it easier to install your siding, and enhance the wall's drying ability.